# The definition of a function in C

Tags: c, function, multiplication

I have an assignment question which ask me about the *definition of a function.* I'm not quite sure how it want me to answer. The question is below:

> Write the definition of a function `multiplier()`, which has two real parameters `n` and `m`, and which returns value of `n` multiplied by `m`

Comment: Do you know how to write a function in C?

Comment: yea, so it just want me to write a function to implement what it want?

Comment: Yes, write the definition for a function named `multiplier` that does what is described.

Comment: There is some question about what it means by “real” parameters. C does not have a standard real type. The author might mean `double` or `float`.

Comment: okay thanks, I was just not sure about what it want

Comment: The phrase "definition of a function" might be ambiguous. One might assume it's asking for a dictionary definition of the word "function". But in fact it's asking for a *function definition* (that's a technical term in the C standard). In other words, you need to write a C function.

Comment: The "definition" and the "implementation" of a function are synonymous in C.

Comment: The "definition" of a function includes its return value, name, parameters (with names) and body.   If there is semicolon instead of a body, then it's a "declaration".

Comment: @Kaz - actually, a function definition is a type of declaration.   A function declaration includes its name, return type, and type of arguments.   A function definition is a declaration that ALSO includes names of used arguments (unused arguments do not need to be named in the definition), and the function block (what you're calling the "body").

Comment: @Peter That's a good correction, except in C, names aren't part of a declaration (e.g. there is no mismatch if multiple declarations of the same function use different parameter names, or no names), and parameters cannot be unnamed in a definition; that's a C++ feature.

Comment: @Kaz -  You're correct that the definition in C requires arguments to be named, even if unused.

Answer (score 0):

> Write the definition of a function `multiplier()`, which has two real parameters `n` and `m`, and which returns value of `n` multiplied by `m`

Lets try to unwrap this, there are no *real*-type in C so *Real* is the code word for `float` or `double`. *Function* is the name of a subroutine.

The wording of the question is vague definition could ask for the optional prototype declaration(the definition of functions which is usually stored in the header files) which is

```c
float multiplier(float,float);
```

or the function could be defined and implemented at the same time

```
float multiplier(float n, float m){
   return (n*m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is,

> Write the definition of a function multiplier(), which has two real parameters n and m, and which returns value of n multiplied by m

A function is a certain way to write a code, that way you can call it in the main, or wherever, and it performs any tasks assign to it. In your case, for your multiplier, it will perform the function of multiplication. Therefore, it would make sense to use two integers in order to perform this task.

To start, since we will be returning an int, we will call it as that. We set it up like this,

*type* *name* (*parameters) 
{

}

in your case, 
int multiplier(*Parameters go here*)

For the code:

```
int multiplier(int m, int n)
{
   return m*n;
}
```

then when we call it in the main, we would pass two numbers for the multiplier and it will return it as a product.

```
int main()
{
  multipler(2, 4); // prints 8
}
```

I hope this helps, I tried to explain it very basic.